# Confluent schema-registry:download not work into pom.xml file when run clean install

Tags: maven, apache-kafka, maven-plugin, confluent-schema-registry

I have the following pom.xml file, my need would be to download the asvc file from the url that provides the kafka registry schema and place it in a directory in my spring boot project. This doesn't happen and I don't receive errors during the clean install phase. Is there something wrong with my pom.xml file? I followed what the official doc available at the following link says https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/develop/maven-plugin.html#workflows-and-examples.

Below is the pom.xml, in the part relating to the build tag you can see the part relating to download:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4</version>
        <relativePath/>
        <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>it.puglia.regione</groupId>
    <artifactId>sgp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>sgp</name>
    <description>Progetto gratuità puglia SGP</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <postgresql.version>42.6.0</postgresql.version>
        <spring-boot-starter-batch.version>3.2.0</spring-boot-starter-batch.version>
        <h2database.version>2.2.224</h2database.version>
        <spring-boot-starter-aop.version>3.1.2</spring-boot-starter-aop.version>
        <spring-boot-starter-actuator.version>3.2.0</spring-boot-starter-actuator.version>
        <resilience4j.version>2.1.0</resilience4j.version>
        <jackson-databind.version>2.15.2</jackson-databind.version>
        <jsoup.version>1.16.2</jsoup.version>
        <flying-saucer-pdf-openpdf.version>9.3.1</flying-saucer-pdf-openpdf.version>
        <itextpdf.version>5.5.13.3</itextpdf.version>
        <jjwt-api.version>0.11.5</jjwt-api.version>
        <jjwt-impl.version>0.11.5</jjwt-impl.version>
        <jjwt-jackson.version>0.11.5</jjwt-jackson.version>
        <springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui.version>2.1.0</springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui.version>
        <javase.version>2.6.0</javase.version>
        <spring-ws-security.version>4.0.9</spring-ws-security.version>
        <jaxws-maven-plugin.version>3.0.0</jaxws-maven-plugin.version>
        <flyway.user>${DB_USERNAME}</flyway.user>
        <flyway.password>${DB_PASSWORD}</flyway.password>
        <flyway.schemas>${DB_NAME}</flyway.schemas>
        <soap.generation.package.isee>it.puglia.regione.sgp.external.ws.classes.isee.generated</soap.generation.package.isee>
        <soap.generation.package.invcivile>it.puglia.regione.sgp.external.ws.classes.invcivile.generated</soap.generation.package.invcivile>
        <qrgen.version>3.0.1</qrgen.version>
        <avro.version>1.11.3</avro.version>
        <avro-maven-plugin.version>1.11.3</avro-maven-plugin.version>
        <avro.generation.package.firma>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</avro.generation.package.firma>
        <kafka-avro.serializer.version>7.5.3</kafka-avro.serializer.version>
        <kafka-schema-registry-client.version>7.5.3</kafka-schema-registry-client.version>
        <kafka-schema-registry-maven-plugin.version>7.5.3</kafka-schema-registry-maven-plugin.version>
        <schema-registry-firma-informatica.url>http://127.0.0.1:8081</schema-registry-firma-informatica.url>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jitpack.io</id>
            <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>confluent</id>
            <url>https://packages.confluent.io/maven/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
            <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
            <version>${avro.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-avro-serializer</artifactId>
            <version>${kafka-avro.serializer.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-schema-registry-client</artifactId>
            <version>${kafka-schema-registry-client.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>${postgresql.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot-starter-batch.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>${h2database.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot-starter-aop.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot-starter-actuator.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>resilience4j-all</artifactId>
            <version>${resilience4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-rest-hal-explorer</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-databind.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>${jsoup.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xhtmlrenderer</groupId>
            <artifactId>flying-saucer-pdf-openpdf</artifactId>
            <version>${flying-saucer-pdf-openpdf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>${itextpdf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jjwt-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${jjwt-impl.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>${jjwt-jackson.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.twilio.sdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>twilio</artifactId>
            <version>10.0.0-rc.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.kenglxn.QRGen</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>${qrgen.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-security</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-ws-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Schema Registry Maven Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
                <artifactId>kafka-schema-registry-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${kafka-schema-registry-maven-plugin.version}</version> 
                <configuration>
                    <schemaRegistryUrls>
                        <param>${schema-registry-firma-informatica.url}</param>
                    </schemaRegistryUrls>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/avroschemas/firma</outputDirectory>
                    <schemaExtension>FirmaInformatica.avsc</schemaExtension>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>rigenerate-wsdl</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>rigenerate.wsdl</name>
                    <value>true</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <!-- WSDL -->
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${jaxws-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>generate-from-isee-service</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>wsimport</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <packageName>${soap.generation.package.isee}</packageName>
                                    <wsdlUrls>
                                        <wsdlUrl>http://127.0.0.1:9000/ws/isee.wsdl</wsdlUrl>
                                    </wsdlUrls>
                                    <sourceDestDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDestDir>
                                    <destDir>${classesDir}</destDir>
                                    <extension>true</extension>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>generate-from-inv-civile-service</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>wsimport</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <packageName>${soap.generation.package.invcivile}</packageName>
                                    <wsdlUrls>
                                        <wsdlUrl>http://127.0.0.1:9001/ws/invCivile.wsdl</wsdlUrl>
                                    </wsdlUrls>
                                    <sourceDestDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDestDir>
                                    <destDir>${classesDir}</destDir>
                                    <extension>true</extension>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <!-- Avro Maven Plugin -->
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
                        <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${avro-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>schemas</id>
                                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>schema</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/avroschemas/firma</sourceDirectory>
                                    <outputDirectory>${avro.generation.package.firma}</outputDirectory>
                                    <stringType>String</stringType>
                                    <fieldVisibility>PRIVATE</fieldVisibility>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```